# Why FutureBuilder does not execute the condition when the data is not yet ready using Provider?

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-futurebuilder

Why doesn't FutureBuilder execute a condition when the data is not ready yet? I.e. block else where '-------------' is not executed.

Before I used provider, that block would execute, i.e. it would show CircularProgressIndicator.

The provider value (ChangeNotifierProvider) is changed in the PaginationAppBar.

```
  Future<List<ProfileData>> fetchProfiles(int page) {
    WebService webService = locator<WebService>();
    return webService.fetchProfiles(Gender.female, page); //future
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pagerModel = context.watch<PagerModel>();
    return FutureBuilder<List<ProfileData>>(
      future: fetchProfiles(pagerModel.page),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final data = snapshot.data;
          debugPrint('snapshot data length ${snapshot.data?.length}');
          if (data!.isEmpty) {
            return const ErrorWithMessage(message: 'data loading error');
          }
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: const PaginationAppBar(Gender.female),
            body: ProfileGrid(data),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return _processError(snapshot);
        } else {
          debugPrint('-------------this else does not execute');
          return const Scaffold(
            appBar: PaginationAppBar(Gender.female),
            body: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: most likely it goes here: `else if (snapshot.hasError)` - add `debugPrint('======= error')` and watch the logs

Comment: @pskink unlikely, since the data arrives and after a short delay the first condition is drawn when the data is ready

Comment: @pskink no output in error condition block

Comment: @pskink in the very beginning of builder it prints `AsyncSnapshot<List<ProfileData>>(ConnectionState.done, [ <here are some data> ], null, null)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257147/discussion-between-rozerro-and-pskink).

Comment: `future: fetchProfiles(pagerModel.page),` Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg